# Заменить текст с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет! Есть блок, в котором есть текст:

```
<div class="block">
  Первое слово
</div>
```

Нужно заменить его, используя JS, чтобы получилось:

```
<div class="block">
  Второе слово
</div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('div.block');
elements.forEach((element) => {
  element.textContent = element.textContent.replace('Первое слово', 'Второе слово');
});
```

```html
<div class="block">
  Первое слово
</div>
<div class="block">
  Первое слово
</div>
<div class="block">
  Первое слово
</div>
```

Comment: а `\n` зачем? И почему не `\r\n` например?

Comment: Старался следовать условиям вопроса буквально. Так-то конечно незачем, потому что все пробельные символы будут нормализованы.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt спасибо, но не совсем то. Наверное моя вина, что не конкретизировал. Нужно заменить конкретно "Первое слово" на "Второе слово". В этом блоке может быть и "Третье слово", но его трогать не нужно) Как быть?

Comment: Отредактировал ответ. Если нужно что-то сложнее, можно использовать регулярные выражения с этим же методом.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt отлично, работает! Но есть проблема. У меня таких идет 3 блока (.block), и скрипт меняет текст только в первом блоке, в остальных остается старый текст. Как быть в такой ситуации?

Comment: Тогда можно, как в последней редакции ответа.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt супер, спасибо! Работает конечно же, но вот вопрос теперь не совсем по теме) Вот тут я указываю так: element.textContent.replace('Текст', '<?=$arItem["TEXT"]?>'). Для каждого такого блока по отдельности выводится его текст через переменную в php. Но в данном случае он во всех блоках выводит только первый текст, предназначенный только для первого блока. Вопрос уже не по теме, я это понимаю, просто может можете помочь)

Comment: К сожалению, я не знаю PHP и как его код взаимодействует с JS, так что, наверное, вам лучше задать новый вопрос с соответствующими тегами и подробным описанием)

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.querySelector('.block').onmousemove = function(){
  setTimeout( () => {
    document.querySelector('.block').innerHTML = 'Второе слово';
  }, 300)
}
```

```html
<div class="block">Первое слово</div>
```